# Jest+Puppeteer after run test TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForSelector' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

How is the correct way to move a group of tests into a separate class or Jest+puppeteer module, which would be called in other tests?
For example, I have a describe with tests, and I want to use this describe in other describe.

**login.spec.js**

```
'use strict'

const testConst = require('./const')
const selectors = require('./selectors')
const action = require('./actions')
const br = require('./browser')
const Auth = require('./login')
   
let page
let browser

beforeAll(async () => {
      // set up Puppeteer
      browser = await br.set_up_Puppeteer(true)
      console.log('browser.isConnected')
      // Web page
      console.log('browser ready')
      page = await br.see_webPage(browser, testConst.browser.url_address)
      console.log('page ready')

      console.log('fill field email and click login btn')
      console.log('logged')

  }, testConst.browser.timeout)

  afterAll(async () => {
      await browser.close()
  }, testConst.browser.timeout)

Auth.login(page)
```

**login.js**

```
'use strict'

const testConst = require('../const.js')
const selectors = require('../selectors')
const action = require('../actions')

class login{
  static async login(page) {

    describe('go to OrgTracker from launchpad', () => {
        test('open card Org Tracker tool in launchpad', async () => {
          await page.waitForSelector(selectors, {
            visible: true
          })
          await page.click(selectors)
          await page.waitForSelector(selectors, {
            visible: true
          })
        }, testConst.browser.timeout)
      })
  }

}

module.exports=login
```

But this combo not working, after run test:login I see error TypeError: Cannot read property 'waitForSelector' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works like this

**login.spec.js**

```
'use strict'
const testConst = require('../const')
const selectors = require('../selectors')
const action = require('../actions')
const br = require('../browser')
const Auth = require('../login')

let page
let browser

const emails_correctData =  testConst.users.correctData.emails
const password_correctData = testConst.users.correctData.passwords

  beforeAll(async () => {
    // set up Puppeteer
      browser = await br.set_up_Puppeteer(true);
      console.log('browser.isConnected');
      // Web page
      page = await br.see_webPage(browser, testConst.browser.url_address, 'user');
      console.log('browser ready');

  }, testConst.browser.timeout)

  afterAll(async () => {
      await browser.close();
  }, testConst.browser.timeout)

  describe('login on system', async() => {

      test('login page as ' + emails_correctData.email1 + ' logged correctly', async () => {
          console.log('fill field email and click login btn')

          await Auth.login( page, emails_correctData.email1, password_correctData.password)
          // full page screenshot
          await action.make_screenshot(page,  testConst.screenshot.path_afterLogin, '_after_login.jpg')
          console.log('logged')
      }, testConst.browser.timeout)

  })
```

**login.js**

```
'use strict'

const testConst = require('../const')
const selectors = require('../selectors')
const action = require('../actions')

class Auth{

    static async login( page, emails_correctData, password) {
      await page.click(selectors.login.signIn).then(async()=>{
         await expect(page.waitForSelector(selectors.login.email)).toBeTruthy()
       })
       console.log('click signIn')
       await action.fillField(page, selectors.login.email, emails_correctData)

       console.log('fillField email')
       await action.fillField(page, selectors.login.password, password)

       console.log('fillField password')
       await page.click(selectors.login.btnLogin).then(async()=>{
         console.log('click btn signIn')
         const userName = await page.$eval(selectors.menu.start, e => e.innerHTML)
         expect(userName).toBe(testConst.users.correctData.userName.userName1)
       },testConst.browser.timeout)
  }
  
}

module.exports=Auth
```

But that doesn't solve my problem. I wanted to specify whole groups of tests in the class and make them where I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `Auth.login(page)` statement at the end of your code. The `page` variable isn't initialized yet at that point. Besides, you're already calling it inside your `beforeAll` which seems about correct, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You are right, I made mistake in the code to the question. no need to call `login` function in `beforeAll`. Thanks for the answer, maybe it will help me.

Comment: @Stiker if it does help (or there isn't another more helpful question), mark the answer as the solution to your question.